# Visual Studio 15 Preview: Xamarin installation

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install Xamarin to the Visual Studio 15 preview. I keep getting the following error:

[image: Visual Studio 15 Xamarin]

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 installed, probably it causes this issue.
Is it possible to install Xamarin for VS 15 Preview side by side with VS 2015 Update 2?

Comment: Why do you have a preview version of Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 installed?  The stable version was already released.  Xamarin is just a template type for Visual Studio at this stage since its free with Visual Studio.  Uninstalll everything then install Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Enterprise directly from the .ISO

Comment: Actually, I have a stable version of Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 installed.
I want to install a preview version of Visual Studio 15 which was announced at Build conference

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the issue.
I need to change Xamarin installation instead of trying to install Xamarin from Visual Studio setup.
So, go to installed programs,

[Xamarin Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCmeN.png)

And then install Xamarin for Visual Studio 15 Preview:

[Xamarin VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhzaT.png)